# When i select course1 right arrow should get down(only for one selected item)

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I have created one sample side menu. When iam selecting one Item(course1) Right Arrow should Show as down arrow in only one `<li>`

But it is in ngFor. It is applying for all menu items(courses). I want which i have select that has to show as down arrow. Here iam attaching image also.
[image]
Please can anyone format the code.

**course.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core' 
import { CourseService } from './course.service'

 @Component({
     selector: 'courses',
     template: `       
     <h2>Courses</h2>
     {{title}}
     <ul>
         <li *ngFor="#course of courses; #i = index">
         <a (click)="onClick(course)">
            <span><i class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-chevron-down]="!isFavorite" 
              [class.glyphicon-chevron-right]="isFavorite"></i> {{ course }} </span>   
         </a>       
         </li>
     </ul>  
     `,
     providers: [CourseService] }) 

 export class CoursesComponent {
     title = "";
     courses;
     isFavorite;

     constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
         this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
         this.isFavorite = new Array(this.courses.length);
     }

     onClick(course) {
         console.log("clicked", course);
         this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
     } 
 }
```

**Here app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'; 
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component'

 @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `<h1>Side Menu</h1>
     <courses></courses>
     `,
     styles: [`
         .glyphicon{
             font-size:26px;
         }
     `],
     directives: [CoursesComponent] }) 

  export class AppComponent {
     post = {
         title: "Title",
         isFavorite: true
     }
     onFavoriteChange($event) {
         console.log($event);
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your use case states that there can be one or many favorite courses.
Issue with your code lays in how you treat `isFavorite`, which has array assigned in ctor and later on you treat it as boolean flag common for all courses, which in turns control all glyphs cause it is single variable bound to glyph on all courses.

**course.component.ts (single fav course)(updated)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular2/core'
import { CourseService } from './course.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
     <h2>Courses</h2>
     {{title}}
     <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
            <a (click)="onClick(course)">
                <span>
                    <i class="glyphicon {{ favorite === course ? 'glyphicon-chevron-right' : 'glyphicon-chevron-down' }}"></i>
                    {{ course }}
                </span>   
            </a>
         </li>
     </ul>  
     `,
    providers: [CourseService]
})

export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "";
    courses; // : Course[];
    favorite = null;

    constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }

    onClick(course) {
        console.log("clicked", course);

        if (this.favorite === course) { // same clicked twice in a row, deselect
            this.favorite = null;
        } else { // new one selected, replace
            this.favorite = course;
        }
    }
}
```

As 1st attempt to make it work I would go with sth like this.

**course.component.ts (multiple fav courses)(updated)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular2/core'
import { CourseService } from './course.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
     <h2>Courses</h2>
     {{title}}
     <ul>
         <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
            <a (click)="onClick(course)">
                <span>
                    <i class="glyphicon {{ isFavorite(course) ? 'glyphicon-chevron-right' : 'glyphicon-chevron-down' }}"></i>
                    {{ course }}
                </span>   
            </a>
         </li>
     </ul>  
     `,
    providers: [CourseService]
})

export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "";
    courses; // : Course[];
    favorites = []; // : Course[];

    constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }

    isFavorite(course): boolean {
        return this.favorites.indexOf(course) !== -1;
    }

    onClick(course) {
        console.log("clicked", course);

        if (this.isFavorite(course)) { // found it! remove
            this.favorites = this.favorites.filter(c => c !== course); // or this.favorites.splice(favIdx, 1);
        } else { // not found? add
            this.favorites.push(course);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope one of the versions helped.

**EDIT:**

ok so I made ng2 stub project with `ng-cli` to check what big no no i have put there... above examples should build now... under regular `ng-cli` started project. Just to be clear, below my setup:

```
$ ng version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 7.2.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.4
@angular/compiler: 2.4.4
@angular/core: 2.4.4
@angular/forms: 2.4.4
@angular/http: 2.4.4
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.4
@angular/router: 3.4.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.4
```

Comment: Those are not working bro. Showing errors. Please give me some other solution. I need that when i have clicked on course1 right arrow should show down(like sub menu).

Comment: checkout code after edit... I fixed mine and your buggy syntax